# What is rev matching, and how do you do it correctly?

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, rpm

I understand that not doing this properly will destroy your transmission/synchros. What's the proper way to do it? I *think* I'm doing it right, but I've found most people's descriptions to be vague and confusing.

In particular, looking at the engine RPM, how do you know what the transmission RPM is to match it? Also, I've noticed that upshifting quickly seems to minimize the need to hit the gas while shifting, but is shifting too fast bad for the clutch?

Comment: This is a question more about driving technique than motor vehicle maintenance. As such, it will likely be put on hold

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers are vague because there is no scientific way to match engine speed to transmission input shaft speed. We do not know what the input shaft speed is. Matching is a learned skill and it varies with different cars and with the age and hence the feel of the clutch pedal.

In a nutshell if when the clutch is let out the tachometer barely changes rpm as the clutch finishes engagement, match has been achieved. If the tach quickly jumps up or down much, match was not achieved. I consider anything under 200 rpm OK. Most people burn in the muscle memory required quickly, a few never quite get it down.

A very quick shift is not ideal. It is hard on the transmission synchromesh parts. On the other hand a slow shift can make matching harder.